# Search result in presented in specific order?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT id FROM films WHERE id IN (90,4,40)
```

result

```
4
40
90
```

but I want it return 90,4,40
what I must do? (mysql)

---

SORRY , but one more question :

SELECT id FROM films WHERE id IN (90,4,40) ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 90, 4, 40) is ok 
but truthfully

```
 for ( $i = 1; $i <10; $id ++ ){
     $IDarray[] = random();
 }


SELECT id FROM films WHERE id IN "(". implode(',',$IDarray). " ) ";
```

I want order by ID as above but ID is random, i want keep order random of ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE `id` WHEN 90 THEN 0
                   WHEN 4 THEN 1
                   WHEN 40 THEN 2
                   ELSE 3
         END CASE
```

OR

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`id`, '90,4,40')
```

OR

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 90, 4, 40)
```

Comment: i want know it can cause slow ? if table contains very many fields

Comment: many fields? this clause can cause the performance degradation if you have a really **lot of rows** in the result, not the fields number

Comment: If it is **a lot** of rows in the result - then they will be sorted in-memory, so this can be an issue, depending on how many rows you have.

Comment: @zerkms: So no, because he's only selecting 3 rows from the table that need to be ordered anyways. At least I'd hope his `id` field is unique.

Comment: @animuson: so? any of expressions above will be evaluated on the result set - this cannot be optimized. i did not say it is a slow process, but i did emphasized that this can be an issue **on a big bunch** of rows only.

Comment: @zerkms: I was merely pointing out that none of these options would cause any noticeable slowness on his data because he's only selecting three rows that get ordered. No matter how many rows he has in his table, MySQL will always find those 3 ID numbers via his WHERE statement and then order them.

Comment: @animuson: again: i emphasized the fact that this can cause any degradation only if he have a lot of rows in the **result**. is that enough clear for you?