# php/Mysql select order by given ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have this variable

`$id = 12;`

I want to select all rows from my table in any order but with the row with id = 12 as the first result. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search result in presented in specific order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748688/search-result-in-presented-in-specific-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY id = 12 DESC, id
```

Comment: Just to add explanation, the `id = 12` is evaluated for each row with a boolean result (`TRUE` or `FALSE`), and since `FALSE` is ordered before `TRUE`, the `DESC` reverses the order so that rows where `id = 12` returns `TRUE` come first.

Comment: In MySQL TRUE is identified with integer 1 and FALSE is identified with integer 0.

Answer (score 2):

You could select first the ones with id=12 and then the others (id!=12).
With an index on id, it shouldn't be slower than requiring the whole table one time.